# Using Tkinter, Threading and After method

Tags: python, selenium, oop, tkinter, sleep

im working on a selenium project using tkinter in python. I want to execute many selenium task at one time(could be up to 100), so I used threading to accomplish this goal, but I came to a problem, due to the fact that I need all individual selenium task to wait a couple seconds between instructions, I used the '.after' method but for some reason my program is still freezing up, I've done a lot of research but I cant seem to find the answer yet. Isn't there a way to use tkinter, threading and some sort of sleeping in python? Do I need to switch to multiprocessing? but I would need all selenium processes to finish within the same 2 minutes and each process takes about a minute.(e.g lets say i start 100, 1 minute processes at 6:00 all task would need to be finished by 6:02)

I created minimal code which mimics my selenium script, so its easier to read, here it is:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
import time
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('700x700')
import threading
class Make:
    def __init__(self,num):
        self.num = num.get()
        Label(root,text='HELLO WORLD WILL PRINT: '+str(self.num)+' times, press go to confirm').pack()
        Button(root, text='go', command=lambda: self.starting()).pack()

    def starting(self):

        for count in range(self.num):
            t = threading.Thread(target=gogogo())
            t.start()

def gogogo():
    tk.Label(root,text='HELLO WORLD').pack()
    root.after(2000,print('Please wait 2 seconds'))
    tk.Label(root,text='You are inside my world').pack()


Label(root,text='How many times should I print: HELLO WORLD').pack()

num = IntVar()
Entry(root, textvariable=num).pack()

Button(root, text='Start', command=lambda: Make(num)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `after()` need function's name without `()` and arguments - and it is called `callback`. If you need arguments then use `lambda` to create function without arguments - `root.after(2000, lambda: print('Please wait 2 seconds'))`. BTW: the same is with `Thread` - it needs also function's name without `()` - `Thread(target=gogogo)`. Both use later `()` to run assigned function. In your code you do `result = gogogo()`, `Thread(target=result)` - so it executes function in main thread and uses result as function which it has to execute in thread. But `gogogo()` returns `None`. The same in `after()`

Comment: BTW: many GUI frameworks can runs only in main thread so using `Label()` in thread can make probem. You may have to use `queue` to send message from thread to main thread and main thread will need `after()` to check periodically if there is new message in queue and add widget in GUI (or replace text in existing widget)

Comment: thanks it worked!!!!!!, but I just realised that the ```   tk.Label(root,text='You are inside my world').pack()``` runs before the 2 seconds are waited, i thought it would follow normal procedure and wait till the line of code before it would be executed?

Comment: `after()` doesn't stop code - it only sends information to `mainloop` to execut function after 2000ms and `mainloop` will do it after 2000ms. And python runs code after `after()` at once. You would need `after(2000ms, other_function)` and in `other_function` you have to add Label

Comment: never mind I found out that I could use time.sleep instead in this method, I was surprised it would work

Comment: inside `thread` you can use `sleep` because it runs in separated thread and it doesn't block main thread and `mainloop()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You main problem is that `after()` and `Thread()` similar to `command=` needs only function's name without `()` and it will later use `()` to execute it.

Other problem is that `after()` doesn't stop code but it only send information to `mainloop` to execute function after `2000ms` and later Python runs at once next line after `after()`. You have to add `Label` in fucntion executed by `after()`

```
def gogogo():
    tk.Label(root, text='HELLO WORLD').pack()
    print('Please wait 2 seconds')
    root.after(2000, next_message) # function's name without ()

def next_message():
    tk.Label(root, text='You are inside my world').pack()
```

---

```
# from tkinter import * # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import time

class Make:

    def __init__(self, num):
        self.num = num.get()

        text = 'HELLO WORLD WILL PRINT: {} times, press go to confirm'.format(self.num)
        tk.Label(root, text=text).pack()

        tk.Button(root, text='go', command=self.starting).pack()

    def starting(self):
        for count in range(self.num):
            t = threading.Thread(target=gogogo) # function's name without ()
            t.start()

def gogogo():
    tk.Label(root, text='HELLO WORLD').pack()
    print('Please wait 2 seconds')
    root.after(2000, next_message) # function's name without ()

def next_message():
    tk.Label(root, text='You are inside my world').pack()

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('700x700')

tk.Label(root, text='How many times should I print: HELLO WORLD').pack()

num = tk.IntVar()
tk.Entry(root, textvariable=num).pack()

tk.Button(root, text='Start', command=lambda:Make(num)).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** Because `gogogo()` runs in separated thread so you can also use `time.sleep()` because it doesn't block `mainloop()` in main thread

```
def gogogo():
    tk.Label(root, text='HELLO WORLD').pack()
    print('Please wait 2 seconds')
    time.sleep(2)
    tk.Label(root, text='You are inside my world').pack()
```