# How to make a button which stops my thread with a while

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a button that stops my thread which has a while in it but I'm not so sure on how to do so. I just basically need to stop the while statement but I'm not sure whether finding a way to stop the thread is a better choice or trying to do something that will stop the while in the thread like using a hotkey and making the stop button use pyautogui to press down that hotkey. I just started to learn all this so please do bear with me. Also any improvements to my code is much appreciated! (Ignore what my stop button command says. I just copied and pasted it there to see if the button would show up, which it did)

```
from tkinter import *
from poke import start
import pyautogui
import sys
import threading

myWindow = Tk()
myWindow.title("TFT Bot")
myWindow.configure(background="#EEEEEE")
Label(myWindow, text="TFT Bot", bg="#EEEEEE", fg="#555555", font="Times 20 bold underline").pack()
myWindow.geometry("600x400+200+250")

exitbutton = Button(myWindow, text="Exit", command=myWindow.destroy)
exitbutton.place(x=285,y=100)
      
startbutton = Button(myWindow, text="Start", command=lambda:threading.Thread(target=start).start())
startbutton.place(x=260,y=200)

stopbutton = Button(myWindow, text="Stop", command=lambda:threading.Thread(target=start).start())
stopbutton.place(x=360,y=400)

startbutton.pack()
stopbutton.pack()
exitbutton.pack()

myWindow.mainloop()
```

My Start function:

```
from pyautogui import *
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard
import random
import win32api, win32con
import sys
def start():

    while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
    #PLAY    
        play = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('./images/play.png', confidence = 0.8)
        if play:
            print ("clicking play")
            pyautogui.moveTo(play)
            time.sleep(1)
            pyautogui.click(play, clicks=2, interval=1)
            time.sleep(0.05)
```

and then its just a bunch of lines that look similar to the first if statement

Comment: you will need to use ```command=lambda:threading.Thread(target=start).start()``` to pass the function to as command argument. Else it will execute the line before you click the button (when in initiates). Also you didnt define any start function. There is also no need to say ```from pyautogui import *``` and ```import pyautogui``` as you will import it twice like this (just use either one not both).

Comment: @sputnick567 actually start function is defined in `from poke import start`  but i think OP should provide information about that start function also.

Comment: @Xitiz yes thank you didnt see that.

Comment: @hwangsa now I am confused what is the main issue for you? Cuz there are multiple issue in your code. Please tell exactly, if possible in short, what is the exact issue of yours?

Comment: @xitiz I just want to know a way I can code my stop button to stop the thread that's from my start button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to stop thread you can try this :

```
import threading
import time

def run(stop):
    while True:
        print('thread running')
        if stop():
                break
                 
def main():
        stop_threads = False
        t1 = threading.Thread(target = run, args =(lambda : stop_threads, ))
        t1.start()
        time.sleep(1)
        stop_threads = True
        t1.join()
        print('thread killed')
main()
```

This is the basic example but very relevant for your issue. For you you may try like this :

```
def start(stop):
    while True:
        play = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('./images/play.png', confidence = 0.8)
        if play:
            print ("clicking play")
            pyautogui.moveTo(play)
            time.sleep(1)
            pyautogui.click(play, clicks=2, interval=1)
            time.sleep(0.05)     
            .......
     if stop() :
         break 

stop_threads=False

startbutton = Button(myWindow,text="Start",command=lambda : threading.Thread(target = start, args =(lambda : stop_threads, )).start())

startbutton.place(x=260,y=200)

def test():
    global stop_threads
    stop_threads=True

stopbutton = Button(myWindow, text="Stop", command=test)
stopbutton.place(x=360,y=400)
```

I have basically created the Thread almost same as yours but the difference is I have used one parameter just to stop that thread.

For more information about it you may visit [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-different-ways-to-kill-a-thread/), there are some other method also to stop thread. But I found this easier for your code.

Comment: It worked perfectly for me! Test it and inform me if it is working or not?

Comment: @xitix The stop button works, but it only works when I alt tab the client I'm trying to use the bot on. Is there a way I can stop it in between the clicks from my start function?

Comment: What do you mean by _" I can stop it in between the clicks from my start function"_? Are you trying to stop thread after some x second?

Comment: I just want to stop the thread when I press the stop button, but it only stops when I alt tab the client the code is clicking on. So when pyautogui locates something, the stop button doesn't stop the thread.

Comment: What do you mean by _"alt tab the client the code is clicking on"_ ? :( actually the issue that button doesn't works could be `time.sleep()` I guess. Cuz time sleep do what it says just freeze all the processing! Looking some part of your code tells me we should use thread but does `myWindow.after()` also works for you? Please look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376970/correct-way-of-using-root-after-and-root-mainloop-in-tkinter) for more info. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62133991/using-tkinter-threading-and-after-method)

Comment: What I meant to say was that if there was nothing for pyautogui to locate, the stop button would only work then. But I figured out a way to make it work now, so I think  my question got answered as it works well now with the advice you gave me. Thank you for helping! @xitiz