# Combining 2 python dictionaries to fetch a value in real time infinite while loop

Tags: python, dictionary, tkinter

I got 2 dictionaries as follows

```
gData = {'43506': '88.70', '43507': '138.60', '43500': '112.60', '43499': '112.95', '41708': '141.50', '41709': '91.00'}

PE_dict {'43507': 'NIFTY21DEC23P21500', '43500': 'NIFTY21DEC23P21450', '41709': 'NIFTY21DEC23P21400'}
```

gData contains token:ltp and PE_dict contains token:symbol as key:value respectively

I am updating gData dict in infinite loop (fetching data into it over websocket) as follows -

```
def live_feed():
    print("Inside live_feed function")    
    global myLabel1
    global pe_ltp
    while not exitProgram:
        print()
        print(gData)
        print("Length of gData - ", len(gData))
        var = gData
        myLabel1.config(text=var)
        time.sleep(0.15)
```

Here is the screenshot of my prototype [image]

myLabel1 (gData) is highlighted in red box, PE_dict is assigned to a OptionMenu highlighted in blue box, n small green box shows pe_ltp (def selected_PE) of selected symbol from OptionMenu

Here is the code for OptionMenu :

```
dropDown_PE = tk.OptionMenu(root, clicked_PE, *PE_dict.values(), command=selected_PE)

def selected_PE(event):
    selected_PE_Strike.config(text="Inside selected_PE()")
    pe_token = list({k for k, v in PE_dict.items() if v == clicked_PE.get()})
    pe_ltp = list({v for k, v in gData.items() if k == pe_token[0]})
    selected_PE_Strike.config(text=pe_ltp)
```

I am able to fetch data in real time in myLabel1 but not able to fetch and update the value of corresponding LTP of selected symbol from dropDown_PE. I am able to fetch the value of LTP in pe_ltp in that selected_PE function but that just fetched latest value of LTP everytime I select different symbol from dropDown_PE, I tried to implement this same logic inside that infinite while loop n started to throw all sorts of errors. I know i got to implement the logic inside that infinite while loop to fetch the real time LTP of selected symbol from dropDown_PE, how can I do that ?

Look at those two yellow boxes their values dont match, while myLabel1 keep getting updated in real time every 0.15 seconds as specified in that infinite while loop
[image]

Edit 1 -

So I completely removed def selected_PE(event): and instead modified live_feed as seen in below attached image, now its working perfectly fine, able to fetch real time ltp as highlighted in red boxes, the only issue is its inside {} since its returning dict, how do I get rid of those {} in top central red box ?

```
def live_feed():
    print("Inside live_feed function")
    # api.subscribe()
    global myLabel1
    global pe_ltp
    while not exitProgram:
        print()
        print(gData)
        print("Length of gData - ", len(gData))
        var = gData
        myLabel1.config(text=var)
        pe_token = list({k for k, v in PE_dict.items() if v == 
        clicked_PE.get()})
        pe_ltp = {v for k, v in gData.items() if k == pe_token[0]}
        selected_PE_Strike.config(text=pe_ltp)
        time.sleep(0.15)
```

[image]

Comment: `time.sleep()` and tkinter do not work together. Here is a link to a question and answer regarding the tkinter millisecond scheduler `after`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64163783/python-tkinter-time-sleep-alternative

Comment: Using `after` will remove the necessity for an infinite while loop and allow you to determine how often you poll the source.

Comment: Understood, so you are recommending calling def live_feed(): using after method with set time interval in milliseconds ? currently I am running it in background thread as follows - t1 = Thread(target=live_feed)
t1.setDaemon(True)
t1.start()     how can I do the same via after method ?

Comment: Or should I call def selected_PE(event) instead in after method ? without touching def live_feed():  where I continue to receive real time data

Comment: Here is a link that asks that question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62133991/using-tkinter-threading-and-after-method

Comment: I think you should update both widgets directly in `live_feed` because it has the newest values.

Comment: maybe you should keep `PE_dict` as `{'NIFTY21DEC23P21500': '43507', ...}`. It would be simpler to convert `NIFTY21DEC23P21500` (from `OptionMenu`) into `43507` which you need to search in `gData`. BTW you search `pe_ltp` using loop but you could run directly `pe_ltp = gData[clicked_PE.get()]`

Comment: yes, trying to update them in live_feed function only but when I used the logic (last 3 lines of selected_PE) inside live_feed its throwing all sorts of errors, its working fine otherwise as selected_PE_Strike label value changes every time I choose different symbol from the dropDown_PE (OptionMenu), how do I implement this logic inside live_feed in the most optimized way ?

Comment: I can't run it but if you have error then show it in question.

Comment: BTW: don't think about `the most optimized way` because it only makes more problems. First you have to create working code.

Comment: BTW: you may find many articles with similar title [Why Premature Optimization Is the Root of All Evil](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/)

Comment: in `selected_PE()` you should get `clicked_PE.get()` and keep in global variable, And in `live_feed` in every loop you should get value from this global variable and use it to update text in label. BTW: if you would keep data as `{'NIFTY21DEC23P21500': '43507', ...}` then it should be simpler `pe_ltp = gData[ PE_dict[ clicked_PE.get() ] ]`. it doesn't need to use for-loop to search values in dictionary.

Comment: If I change the format of PE_dict as suggested by you then in dropDown_PE i can only view tokens, I need to see the symbol for clear view, is there any way I can directly fetch key of corresponding value from dropDown_PE when I say  pe_ltp = gData[clicked_PE.get()]

Comment: in `OptionMenu`  you can use `.keys()` instead of `.values()` and you will have correct values.

Comment: BTW: at this moment you can use `pe_token = [ PE_dict.[clicked_PE.get()] }` instead of using `for`-loop in `pe_token = list({k for k, v in PE_dict.items() if v == clicked_PE.get()})`

Comment: pe_token = [ PE_dict.[clicked_PE.get()] }  is throwing error

Comment: Please check the newly added Edit 1-

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create *set* (not *dict*) for variable `pe_ltp`, just get the value using `gData[pe_token]` whereas `pe_token` is the *key* from `PE_dict` based on the selected value in `OptionMenu`.  Note that it is better to use `.after(...)` to replace the while loop and `time.sleep()` which are not recommended in a GUI application.

```py
def live_feed():
    # fetch data from websocket and update gData
    ...
    myLabel1.config(text=gData)
    # get the key from PE_dict based on the selected value in the OptionMenu
    pe_token = [k for k, v in PE_dict.items() if v == clicked_PE.get()][0]
    # get the value from gData based on pe_token
    pe_ltp = gData[pe_token]
    # update label
    selected_PE_Strike.config(text=pe_ltp)
    # schedule to run live_feed() 0.15 second (150ms) later
    selected_PE_Strike.after(150, live_feed)
```

Comment: Appreciate your input but this after method isnt working well for me, tried everything since morning. Here is my optionmenu code - dropDown_PE = tk.OptionMenu(root, clicked_PE, *PE_dict.values())
dropDown_PE.pack()     I am currently setting default as follow -  clicked_PE.set("Please select strike price")     how can I assign first value of *PE_dict.values() or simply PE_dict instead of this string msg ?

Comment: @ScalperVegeta You can use back your while loop instead of `.after()`.  I just recommend to use `.after()`.

Comment: Use `clicked_PE.set(list(PE_dict.values())[0])`.

Comment: Thanks, that last input worked like wonders.